# Should I add npm-shrinkwrap.json, package-lock.json or yarn.lock?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg

I am shipping a package that I only compile using tsc ( typescript compiler ) and I am expecting the consumers to get dependencies installed when they install my package using npm or yarn.

I don't want want to lock down consumers to using npm or yarn but definitely want the same version of dependency to be installed. What is the recommendation around this?

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Lockfiles like `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` will be ignored by NPM.

Also if `typescript` is your only dependency and you have it listed under `devDependencies`, any users of your package will not install any sub-packages from your package anyways, since `devDependencies` are not installed recursively.